# how to use CKEDITOR. inside foreach in php

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

i have a foreach loop that display record from a table , but CKEDITOR replace only first record .
when i click to some record to updated from html table it just format only first record

```
//CKEDITOR.replace('about'); 
<?php foreach($GetAll as $get) : ?>
    <div class="form-group"> <label>Short Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="about" rows="3"><?php echo $get->description?></textarea> 
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        CKEDITOR.replace('about');
        </script>
     </div> 
<?php endforeach ; ?>
```

Comment: //CKEDITOR.replace('about');
<?php foreach($GetAll as $get) : ?>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Short Description</label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="about" rows="3"><?php echo $get->description?></textarea>
<script type='text/javascript'>CKEDITOR.replace('about');</script></div>

<?php endforeach ; ?>

Comment: What Should I Do With !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [CKEditor.replaceAll()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replaceAll) instead of [CKEditor.replace()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace).

Note, that you should call this method just once after the DOM elements are created not in every iteration of the loop. Then each element have to have a different name but use the same class. For example:

```
<textarea class="about form-control" name="about1"></textarea>
<textarea class="about form-control" name="about2"></textarea>
<textarea class="about form-control" name="about3"></textarea>

<script type='text/javascript'>
CKEDITOR.replaceAll('about');
</script>
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/GbvqBRXt5GcTLVygNvIB?p=preview

Comment: same problem i remove
<script type='text/javascript'>
CKEDITOR.replaceAll('about');
</script> 
from the loop but its the same , also im just starting learning php

Comment: See: http://plnkr.co/edit/GbvqBRXt5GcTLVygNvIB?p=preview

Comment: work fine , thanks for all members . 
really a good feeling to see people sharing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace all textarea elements to CKEditor simply call:

```
<script>
  /* Replace all <textarea> elements in the page. */
  CKEDITOR.replaceAll();
</script>
```

After all textarea elements;

> [CKEditor.replaceAll()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replaceAll)